# Proof of funds for 3 month USA trip?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, proof-of-funds

Questions are in bold, other information is not in bold.

I am a UK citizen, 22 years old and will be meeting my boyfriend for the first time, staying with him (and his parents) and will have $1000 approximately when I arrive, being paid from then on every 2 weeks from a disability benefit I am able to be paid out-of-country for 12 weeks in total. I will be filling out my ESTA and getting plane tickets for 9th October-22nd December. (I will be able to provide proof that my "income" will be paid continuously throughout my stay and has been paid on time, every time for the last 6 months)

**Will not having 3 months worth of money be a problem for customs?**

**Will I be refused entrance to the USA by stating I am visiting my boyfriend?**

**I also have no ties to the UK other than caring for my deaf mother. How do I avoid this being a problem?**

I receive around $1500 per month. I do not attend university, I will not be taking leave from any employment and do not have a car or my own house (I have access to my parents car and live at their house) 
Boyfriend works a full time job and plans to support me throughout my stay, I also have proof of his mother inviting me to stay from the 9/10 - 22/12.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Tahli, this is a very vgue question which we are not really in a position to answer. If you can ask specific questions, then we can probably answer those. Also please tell us what country you are from.

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking about proof of funds requirements, but seems like she could have problems with visa due to ties to returning home

Comment: You say you will be "paid" every two weeks.  Paid by whom and for what?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still am not sure as to what it is you are asking. Would you mind rendering the question a bit more explicit?

Comment: You should always answer truthfully. Don't try to downplay or hide your relationship. Given the information here, if you've never travelled to the US before, I'd expect you to receive a longer than usual interview, but most likely be admitted in the end. If you have been to the US before, then just swipe your passport at a kiosk and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Tell them that you're visiting the US for two weeks. Get a return ticket for 2 weeks and then cancel it later on when you enter the US. Asking for a 3 month entry can serve as a red flag and cbp agents are always agitated and annoyed. If you ask for a 2 week entry, they'll end up giving you 3 months anyways.

Comment: and is this totally legal?

Comment: To be honest. Intentions change as a person enters the US territory.  As long as you're doing everything legally, I think you can circumnavigate through things. But remember, it's the CBP that gives people entry for 3 to 6 months to begin with.